# Using transformation parameters in ArcMap?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap

I have transformation parameters for location which name is MILAS.

[image]

[image]

So, how I can use this parameters for transformation? Which folder should I put?

Link to a copy of the file:  https://files.fm/u/wm6gfzgp

Comment: If you want a more focused or detailed answer, you'll have to show the contents (obfuscate/change the values if you need to) of the transformatoin file(s).

Comment: file donwload link:   https://files.fm/u/wm6gfzgp   Thanks.

Comment: actually ı try to transfor ITRF96 to ED50

Answer (score 3):

------------ New answer 13 Oct 2018 --------------
More information after a link with data was provided.

I looked at all the files. Some files list corresponding points in two different coordinate reference systems (CRS). All points are in a projected CRS but that information is not given. The values are mostly 6- and 7-figure numbers like:

yyyyyy.yyy and xxxxxxx.xxx

They are probably UTM coordinates with easting values labeled as 'Y' and northing labeled as 'X' in the files. There are also some 5 figure (xxxxx.xxx) coordinates that could be in a local CRS.

The files or data often refer to geodetic CRS as well like ED50 and ITRF 2005 or ETRS89.

Most files, with extensions DNS or CKS, look like they're from land surveying software. There's also an Excel spreadsheet with several groups of control points. Each group also has 4 transformation parameters (probably) associated with it, plus a scale factor and rotation (?) plus some error statistics.

One datasheet in the Excel spreadsheet has a summary transformation:

```
> B1= 0.999987661232  B3= 23.255104690349
> B2= 0.000013755050  B4= -144.290031304926
> Dönüklük= 0.000876 grad
> Ölçek= 12.339 ppm (1:81045)
```

I believe that B1-B4 are parameters for a 2D conformal (similarity) transformation.

You can look about 1/3 down the page of this [Transform](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/how-transform-works.htm) to see what the equation looks like. This help doc is for an ArcInfo Workstation command and supports coverages only. You also can't specify the transformation parameters--the tool does it for you.

When converting coordinate reference systems, ArcGIS doesn't support transformations between two projected CRS. I know you can set translation, rotation, scale values for CAD layers.

Depending on which ArcGIS version you're using, we do have an ED50-ETRS89 transformation (ED_1950_To_ETRS_1989_9 although the accuracy is stated to be around 2 m.

----------- Original answer below ---------------------

ArcGIS has a few ways for someone to add a custom geographic/datum transformation. The most straightforward is described below.

The supported equation-based methods are geocentric translation, coordinate frame, position vector, Molodensky-Badekas, longitude rotation, unit change, null. By equation-based, I mean that there are a few parameters and the transformation doesn't need a file of offsets.

Supported file-based methods are NADCON, HARN, GEOCON, and NTv2.

You can use the [Create Custom Geographic Transformation tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-custom-geographic-transformation.htm) to define either an equation-based or file-based transformation.

If you're defining a file-based transformation, for the Dataset name parameter, use Dataset_FILENAME (no extension) and put the file in the ArcGIS install's pedata folder under the appropriate method name like ntv2 or nadcon. If using NTv2, you can optionally add a folder which you would include in the parameter name like Dataset_monaco/myfile if the data is for Monaco and is called myfile.gsb.

If you're using an equation-based method, be careful with coordinate frame, position vector, and Molodensky-Badekas. Coordinate frame and Molodensky-Badekas use a different rotation convention than position vector. It's easy to switch between them--just change the signs of the rotations. These equation-based methods (plus geocentric translations) use translations, rotations, and scale plus a 3D Cartesian point location for Molodensky-Badekas in 3D Cartesian space thus dX,dY,dZ, rotations around the 3 axes plus a scale difference.

In general, also be careful to set the source/target coordinate systems correctly so that they match the direction of the transformation and that the units match--meters for the translations, arc-seconds for the rotations, and parts per million for the scale difference.

Disclosure: I work for Esri.

Comment: I can t see extension like NADCON, HARN, GEOCON, and NTv2                                    my transformation folder :https://files.fm/u/wm6gfzgp